# When to get a patent after designing a product

Tags: design-patent

I am thinking of designing a particular phone case. My question is normally what is the process between the design stage up to pitching the design? Is it simply:

Design product
Get a patent on design
Pitch design to company

Also how much does a patent cost in £?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design, initiate some form of protection, then pitch - would be my recommendation. The protection may not need to be a patent application and you certainly don't need to wait for a patent to issue. The protection for a phone case might be trademark, design registration or could be a patent application if there are unique functional aspects.